ESLint not recognizing files in non-standard folder structure
Installing ESLint and receiving the following error when issuing the command npm run lint:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.57.0

No files matching the pattern "**/aura/**/*.js" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

I am currently running a non-standard folder structure under force-app, such as force-app/project01/default/lwc and force-app/project02/default/lwc etc.
My .eslintrc.json file is located under the root directory for the project, and there are LWCs in each of the projectXX folders that should be picked up.
I have verified that the folders are deploying to a Developer Org and Sandbox correctly, so the issue isn't the folder structure.

After a fair bit of research, it was determined that the solution was to modify the key-value pair "lint": "eslint **/{aura,lwc}/**/*.js" under scripts in the package.json file. The appropriate key-value pair is: "lint": "eslint force-app/**/default/lwc".
If you wanted to check Aura and LWC components, you would set the value as: "eslint force-app/**/default/{lwc,aura}".
The documentation for linting is all over the place in quality, with many broken links and outdated references. Just wanted to drop this here in case it helps save someone else a few hours of Googling.
